# where I can get dart.io RawSocket examples?

Tags: sockets, dart

I need to connect to remote unix system and I need to use raw socket of dart.io.

My question is where I can get dart.io RawSocket examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see some usages in [RawSocket tests](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/tests/standalone_2/io/raw_socket_test.dart).